# CSS/JQuery: Animation effect on hovered image?

Tags: jquery, css

My website's menu has text images for each button instead of pure text.
When the button is hovered, the image is replaced with another one that looks the same but has a out glowing effect on it.

I want the new image to be shown with a fade in animation when hovered.
How can this be achieved with CSS or JQuery?

Comment: could you please provide a sample of code where you get stuck? I think you tried something and failed with that, so please let us know this things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a source that looks like a solid tutorial to achieve the effect you're looking for:

Example: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/fade-method2.html

Tutorial: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-cross-fade-transition/

Comment: Yeah this is what I wanted thanks... Didnt think I would have to wrap it inside a sibling div as mentioned in the tutorial... Guess this will do.

Comment: yeh i know. The thing is, it takes 1 minute for someone to answer my question, and when i click to accept it, it tells me i gotta wait 10 minutes to accept it, so i end up closing the page without waiting, well, i guess a little patience wont hurt. thanks again

Comment: Ah, touche. Didn't know there was a delay. Thanks!